# Netsuite Advanced PDF footer centering issue

Tags: html, css, netsuite, freemarker

I am customizing forms in NetSuite and have gotten everything to work as I would want, except the footer. For some reason the text-align: center function is working based on the number of characters in the row of the footer, rather than the center of the page. Below are images of my code and print examples that show the error better. The only difference in the code between footer code images 1 and 2 is that I removed the word "number" in row 55 to depict the centering is based on characters.
[Footer Code 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rT9tG.png)

[Footer Print 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7HgE.png)

[Footer Code 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWKRP.png)

[Footer Print 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPaYP.png)

Comment: When you have code it is useful to include it as code blocks. If code is given many people will just copy it and provide a fix in their answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to show the borders on your tds you'd get a better sense of what's going on. Basically you are not providing hints for the td and table sizes so the normal table width processing is happening. ie. the tables will only be wide enough to hold the text so they appear to be text size based.

Also I suspect you have a lot more markup than you need. The following will give you what I think you are looking for. Note that you may want to play with padding to get the correct left and right alignments.

```
<macro id="nlfooter">
    <hr />
    <table class="footer" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" colspan="4">email</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="6">Phone</td>
            <td align="right" colspan="4">Page info</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td align="center" colspan="14">
                <b>Thank you</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</macro>
```