# Issue while trying to set center alignment of td contents

Tags: html, pdf, netsuite

What have I searched so far?

[Netsuite Advanced PDF footer centering issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72692255/netsuite-advanced-pdf-footer-centering-issue)

This post has already been checked but not helpful for me.

**Issue details**

I am trying to center the td contents in NetSuite Advanced PDF HTML Template. could you kindly suggest that why it does not center the td contents in preview?

**it looks perfectly fine when I open the template. Screenshot is below**

[image]

**When i look at preview, it looks below**

[image]

**HTML Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE pdf PUBLIC "-//big.faceless.org//report" "report-1.1.dtd">
<pdf>
<head>
</head>
<body padding="0.25in 0.24in 0.25in 0.25in" size="Letter">
   <#if record.item?has_content>
     <table style="width: 100%; border: 1px solid red;">
       <tr>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
            REMIT TO:<br />Company Name here<br />Address Line here with<br/>Another address line Code
         </td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">
            REMIT TO:<br />Company Name here<br />Address Line here with<br/>Another address line Code
         </td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">
         INVOICE<br/>123456789012345<br/>12-January-2023
         </td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     </#if>
</body>
</pdf>
```

Answer (score 0):

The BFO generator which converts the XML into PDF does not support all CSS styles.  However, for text alignment you can use the supported `text-align` attribute instead.  In other words, instead of using

```
 style="text-align: center;"
```

you can use

```
text-align="center"
```

See the page on `text-align` at [the BFO website](https://bfo.com/products/report/docs/tags/atts/text-align.html).

Comment: Shouldn't the question be retagged XML or XHTML and HTML removed?